# Python GUI button trying to toggle a label image

Tags: python, tkinter

I've created a GUI with a toggle button which toggles the button text LED ON, LED OFF. I've now added a label with an image and I would like to try to make the label image toggle when the button is pressed.

I've looked up some examples but I can't quite see how, or where, to add the code to make the label image toggle as well. I tried to add a piece of code into the first part of my IF statement, using label.config but I was trying things I had read on the forums but in the end it didn't work. So I've come to ask for advice.

The error I get is ....
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'......which i don't understand.

Thanks for any help.

My code....

```
# Idle 07_02_LED ON using GUI
from time import sleep

from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self, master): 
            frame = Frame(master)
            frame.pack()
            Label(frame, text='Turn LED ON').grid(row=0, column=0)
            Label(frame, text='Turn LED OFF').grid(row=1, column=0)

            self.button = Button(frame, text='LED 0 ON', command=self.convert0)
            self.button.grid(row=2, column=0)

            self.LED = Label(frame, image=logo).grid(row=2, column=1)

    def convert0(self, tog=[0]):

        tog[0] = not tog[0]
        if tog[0]:
            print('LED 0 OFF')
            self.button.config(text='LED 0 OFF')
            self.LED.config(image = logo2)
        else:
            print('LED 0 ON')
            self.button.config(text='LED 0 ON')
            self.LED.config(image = logo)


root = Tk()
logo = PhotoImage(file="C:\My Documents\MyPictures\Green LED.gif")
logo2 = PhotoImage(file="C:\My Documents\My Pictures\Red LED.gif")

root.wm_title('LED on & off program')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having read some more posts, and particularly one answered by @Nick Meharry, I found I had to split the following line into 2 parts.

self.LED = Label(frame, image=logo).grid(row=2, column=1)

So it works if I do it like this....

self.LED = Label(frame, image=logo)

self.LED.grid(row=2, column=1)

And by the power of greyskull it works!

Comment: this is because `self.LED(...).grid(...)` returns None. Python always returns the result of the last method in the chain, and `grid` (and `pack`) always return `None`.